# Dynamic allocation and large data structures in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

Lately, I learned there is a consensus among C++ programmers that the `new`, `delete` and `delete[]` operators should be avoided as often as possible, as already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620385/why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-use-new) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22146094/why-should-i-use-a-pointer-rather-than-the-object-itself). While searching, I even stumbled upon an [April Fools' joke](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/04/01/cpp-will-no-longer-have-pointers/) stating that these operators would become deprecated in C++20.

I happen to write and maintain a C/C++ program, written in such language in order to carry on useful libraries and classes written by other programmers. As it must run in quite limited environments (i.e., old Linux distributions with the bare minimum in terms of programs), I can't rely on features brought C++11 and later versions (such as [smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one)), and I sticked so far to a mix of C and Java programming habits while expanding my program. Among others, I used quite often dynamic allocation with `new` and `delete` - which sounds, of course, to be a problem.

To ease the maintenance of my code by future programmer(s), I would like to minimize dynamic allocation with said keywords in my code. The problem is that my program has to manage some quite large data structures used for (almost) the entire execution. As a consequence, I struggle to figure out why I should avoid dynamic allocation in these situations.

To simplify, consider I have a data structure (modeled as an object) worth 10 Megaoctets which is used for the entire execution of the program and which the size in memory can increase over time. My questions are the following:

- Is dynamic allocation of the object with `new` still a bad practice in this particular context ? What are the better alternatives ?
- Suppose now I instantiate somewhere in my program a new object without using `new`, do some operations on it which could slightly change its size, then use a method to insert it in my data structure. How does it work, memory-wise, if automatic allocation (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new)) is used ?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Vectors have been with the language for quite some time, and is often a good replacement for `new[]` and `delete[]`. And many parts of the standard library is implemented in header files only, meaning they are part of your program once you build it and doesn't rely on external libraries.

Comment: Unfortunelty if you are living in a C++03 world you're still going to have `new` and `delete`.  You can minimize them though.  If you need a collection of thing, use a vector instead of newing up an array.  You can also write your own RAII smart pointers, or find a library that has already done so.  The big issue with `new` is that you have to manually verify that the memory is deallocated in every control path.  That is a pain and is error prone.  Hiding the resource allocation and release in a RAII manner makes you code a lot less likely to have these bugs.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but an alterantive solution to your issue. Sometimes, if it is worth the trouble, you can build a development chain for your older platfroms to support newer langauge standards. For instance, we are maintaining a fully c++11 compliant build environment for a older linux target (mandaated by the customer) whose native development environment is only partially c++11 compliant.

Comment: @NathanOliver Just to make sure (maybe I should have mentioned `vector` in my statement; maybe I'll edit later): let's say I have an array which is several Mo worth (it's the case in practice). I replace it with a vector, without using dynamic allocation (so, in my case, without using `new`), which is a member element of another class. If I dynamically allocate an instance of such class then fill my vector to be equivalent in practice to my former array (again, not using dynamic allocation for the elements), will everything be stored in the heap as if I manually managed the array ?

Comment: @je Yes.  Here is a very nice "picture" about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55478523/how-does-stdvector-support-contiguous-memory-for-custom-objects-of-unknown-siz/55478808#55478808

Comment: @NathanOliver Many thanks for that. I think I'm getting some idea of how I should handle my memory allocations to minimize `new` now. Maybe I'll update this question later.

Comment: @JefGrailet You're welcome.  If you wind up coming up with a new question post a new question instead of modifying this one.  You don't want to invalidate the answers you already have by changing the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using boost smart pointers.

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/smart_ptr/doc/html/smart_ptr.html

They are very similar to the C++ 11 smart pointers, but available as a library which should work in pre C++ 11 environments.  If you decide to go this way, you may also want to look at this

[How to include only BOOST smart pointer codes into a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512823/how-to-include-only-boost-smart-pointer-codes-into-a-project)

Now, I'm wondering if you are confusing the new/delete functions with dynamic allocation in general.  Smart Pointers are still dynamic allocation, however they are able to clean themselves up so that you don't have to remember too.  That's why they are preferred over using new/delete (malloc/free, etc), they are much less likely to lead to memory leaks.

Automatic allocation is fine when the object lifespan allows it, but if you need the object to persist outside of the function it was declared in, you'll need dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: This looks like a nice alternative for my situation. I can't guarantee I will put it as main answer, depending on what other people might provide, but it's still a good answer to me.

Answer (score 0):

> Is dynamic allocation of the object with `new` still a bad practice in this particular context?

Yes, it's bad to have a `new` in your code mainly because of memory leaks if `delete` or `delete[]` isn't called, especially in the face of exceptions.

> What are the better alternatives?

Write smart pointers and have them either call `new` themselves or be called with a `new` expression:

```
myUniquePtr<myObj> obj_ptr(new myObj);
```

and then use RAII to have their destructors call `delete` or `delete[]`.

Make your smart pointer behave as naked pointer in every other way (overload `operator->` *etc*). Then it'll work in your code with the same syntax as your raw pointers did without having to worry about whether a heap object is deleted at the end of a it's life-cycle no matter what paths the code can take.